# ASP MVC routing rest api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

i would like to create rest api but I have problem with routing.
This url is ok: `localhost/project/controller/action/id`, but i would like this url `localhost/project/controller/id` too.
For example: `localhost/project/article/5`: `ArticleController.Get(int id)`
This is my code:
Project controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("project/{id}")]
public JsonResult Get(int id)
{
}
```

Route config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Api",
                url: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

When i call url localhost/project/article/5, error message is A public action method '5' was not found on controller 'ArticleController'.

Where is problem? Thanks

Comment: Which version of mvc are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

**Example:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("project/{controller}/{action}/{id}")]
public JsonResult Get(int id)
{
}
```

OR

[Default Route Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

**Example:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Api",
                url: "project/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
```

As Per your Requirement, your Routing is:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("project/article/{id:int}")]
public JsonResult Get(int id)
{
}
```

OR

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Api",
                    url: "project/article/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "ArticleController", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this dont work correctly. I need map url localhost/project/article/5 to ArticleController.Get(int id)

Comment: I am sorry, it doesnt work correctly. Error message is A public action method '5' was not found on controller

Comment: I created simple example ApiController: `
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/example")]
        public void Get(int id)
        {
            
        }` When i call url api/example/1 return 404

Comment: No , you try like `[HttpGet] [Route("api/example/{id:int}")] public void Get(int id) { }` @bluray

Comment: @bluray. sorry for my mistake I update `"/project/article/{id:int}")` to `"project/article/{id:int}")`

Comment: I doesnt work. I dont know where is problem. Server still return 404

Comment: add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` this into `RouteConfig.cs` file.@bluray

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143775/discussion-between-ashiquzzaman-and-bluray).